# SSIS Derived column Transformation setting to BOOL with UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM

Tags: ssis

I have a Flag which needs to be set to 1 or 0. so i used Derived column transformation to convert it to bool 
as you can se the code it works only when i use an OR operator for both Y and N . 
This code below works for IF Flag is  Y and N condition

```
(DT_BOOL)(Flag == "Y" ? 1 : 0) || (DT_BOOL)(Flag == "N" ? 0 : 1)
** working only when FLAG = (Capital)Y OR N *****************
```

but if my Flag is small 'n' it does not work it still sets to TRUE 
I want to make it UPPER and TRIM it at the same time . Which i am having hard time to figure out .
This is my code but it does not work

```
(DT_BOOL)(UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM
    (Flag == "Y" ? 1 : 0)
)))
   ||(DT_BOOL)(UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(Flag == "N" ? 0 :1)
))) ***** this code is not working *****************
```

Thanks for your time.

[PLEASE look at Tranformation Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANHVa.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
(DT_BOOL)(UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(Flag))) == "N" ? 0 :1)
```

Comment: thanks did not even thought of that was close though . Thanks a lot

Comment: do you know why i need a OR || for both Y and N

Comment: You shouldn't need the OR || as long as Flag will always be Y,y,N or n.  If the Flag variable holds other values then you will.  If it fails with out the OR ||, let me know what you are getting.

Comment: It is for a Checkbox . Once i import the column based on 1 or 0  the checkbox will be checked or unchecked.